# Generating just a SHA-256 hash from the Linux command line

Tags: linux, checksum

I'm looking for a single command that emits *just* the sha256 hash, as a hexadecimal number, of the contents of a single supplied file.

I am aware of `shasum -a 256`, `openssl dgst -sha256`, `sha256sum` et al. but they all emit other information together with the checksum and I would like to avoid the need for post-processing the result with `sed` or some such.

Comment: What's wrong with shasum -a 256 file | awk '{ print $1 }' ?

Comment: Where’s the problem with `shasum -a 256 filename.txt | cut -f 1 -d " "`?

Comment: `I'm looking for` I believe your question is off topic for stackoverflow - you are searching for a utility, which is off topic here. There is no such "utility" that I know of - if you want one, just write such. Still, it's trivial to do `single_command() { shasum -a 256 "$1" | cut -f 1 -d " "; }` and add that to your shell. You may also consider posting patches to the utilities you mentioned as some additional command line option.

Comment: @KamilCuk This is actually in the context of shell script programming, this is why I care about the output format, but I do not know whether that is enough to make it on topic. There are many other similar questions on SO already, though.

Comment: @RamanSailopal both the `shasum` + post processing solutions are incorrect if the file name contains e.g, control characters, which is one of the reasons "I would like to avoid the need for post-processing" in my shell script.

Comment: `shasum + post processing solutions are incorrect if the file name contains e.g, control characters`  This is a programming problem instead, that can be easily solved. So paste the file content on stdout to `sha256` - that way it will always print `<sha> -`. Most probably you have unrelated quoting error in your script that is unrelated to your question - remember to check your scripts with shellcheck.net . Not only that, coreutils `sha256sum` has the helpful `-z --zero` option just for that case, so `sha256sum --zero "$file" | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'` looks safe to me anyway.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks, the `--zero` option and the pipe-trick does indeed seem to make safe post-processing easier. Unfortunately I need a single command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```
sh -c 'shasum < "$1" | cut -d" " -f1' -- "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following perl one-liner actually seems to satisfy all my stated requirements:

```
perl -e 'use Digest::SHA;' -e 'use warnings;' -e 'use strict;' -e 'use autodie;' -e 'my $sha = Digest::SHA->new(256); open my $fh, $ARGV[0]; $sha->addfile($fh, "b"); print $sha->hexdigest . "\n";' "$file"
```

In particular it is safe for "funny" file names and can be used for arbitrary shell scripting, including as a `find --exec` argument (which is one thing I need it for).

(I have not written in Perl for a very long time, so the above can probably be improved.)

Comment: The `sh -c 'sha256sum < "$1" | awk "{print \$1}"' --` is also a oneliner... There is nothing particular in perl to use it. You may use any scripting language for that matter.

Comment: @KamilCuk Excellent! it is also shorter and clearer than my Perl snippet. Please add it as an answer.